# Checkedlistbox, Textboxes, Output

Tags: winforms, checkbox, textbox

I'm a novice in programming and I'm seeking advice on my program in visual basic (visual studio 2010).

I'll describe my aims of the program and how I've created a mock up.

My main interface will have several tabs. **Within each tab**, there will consist of a few textboxes  for entering data and a few checkedlistboxes with a list of items in each of them. 
What I'd like to do is to gather all the information inputted and/or clicked by a user of the program and to assimilate the information to a pre-formatted text box, that will give me the option to output it to a file. I'd like the pre-formatted textbox to gather the data from the different textboxes and checkedlistboxes from the various tabs. I can give an example (non-code) of what I mean:

```
Tab 1 of application:
textbox asking for name
textbox asking for date
checkedlistbox with items ("green", "blue", "red")

Tab 2 of application:
textbox asking for name of country
textbox asking for citizenship
checkedlistbox with items ("north", "south", "east", "west")

Tab 3 of application:
textbox that is "preformatted" to grab the data from the first two tabs so that I can save it to a textfile that would look like this 

My name is Billy
Today's date is 31JAN2010.
I like: green blue red,

I come from United States of America.
I am American.
I am from the region of South
```

As of now, the method I'm using is largely inefficient. I'm just not knowledgable enough yet to do what I want do I've resorted to this strategy:

For checkedlistitems, I output the list of items to a textbox. I make this box invisible to the user. I then call this box in my tab 3, which has a button and text area. The button portion automatically codes the "preformatted" text and its a matter of referencing the invisible textbox which contains the item lists that were checked. One problem with this, or how I've programmed the checkedlist box, is that If I check something, and then uncheck it, it still appears in my tab 3 textbox.

For example, If I was a user using the 2nd tab and I clicked "South" but then unclick it and click "North", the textbox says

I am from the region of South North

I'm not sure which property or where in my code I need to alter so that it can remove items. I'm using a for loop to grab the items and don't have my code on hand.

In general, I'm just looking for strategies for programming something like this that will be efficient compared to what I have. Any suggestions / examples / code is well appreciated.

Comment: Window Form or ASP.Net? Please at least buy a book and start reading it. If you have any question, come back and ask here.

Comment: Hi, it's a windows form. I've been reading and learning by example from web lectures and video series. I'm just asking for input on design strategies as I've posted mine which I don't think is the best.

Comment: what programming language?

Comment: If you have code ... post it and I can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

For your checkedlistbox, you can use the even SelectedIndexChanged that way when you change the selection, you won't have that problem:

example of how to use:

If you have a simple label for example :

```
Label1.Text = "I am from the region of " & checkedlistbox1.selecteditem.value
```

Btw in your case I don't think a for loop is necessary.

If you wish for information try w3schools or msdn.

Regards